# How to dynamically set the argument to $_GET or $_POST?

Tags: php

I'm writing a function in php to check, if all arguments are set. This is for preventing the program to crash when a argument isn't set.

Unfortunately I get this error:

`Notice: Undefined variable: _POST`

The code running is the following:

```
# check for the right arguments
function checkArguments($type, $arg_array) {
    # $type is either 'GET' or 'POST'
    # $arg_array is an array with all the arguments names

    foreach($arg_array as $arg) {
        print(${"_" . $type}["name"]);
        $type = "_" . $type;
        if(!isset($$type[$arg])) {
            $missing[] = $arg;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sure you want this `if(!isset($$type[$arg])) {` as in double dollar sign `$$type`, note this will not issue an error as PHP has what is called a variable variable.  Maybe it's what you mean, I give up trying to figure that out about 4 years ago....  and chalked it up to a bad practice to implement such thing.  Too error prone, to hard to read.  Not to mention it always seems like a typo, not something that should be valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HI I will assume you wanted a variable variable, I try to avoid them as they are very hard to read in code. It also breaks ( or doesn't work in ) most IDE editors.

One thing I just saw that is relevant.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

> Please note that variable variables cannot be used with PHP's Superglobal arrays within functions or class methods. The variable $this is also a special variable that cannot be referenced dynamically.

The `$_POST` would be counted among the "Superglobal" as is `$_GET`

Answer (score 1):

You could assign them to a temporary variable and use that.

```
$arr = $_GET;
if ($type == "POST") $arr = $_POST;
```

Comment: Thank you. Didn't thought about this solution somehow. Do you know why the dynamic name approach above doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, `$$type`  unless you really want a variable variable, that is a thing, but most ppl are not familiar with it.